# Make two numbers co-prime while preserving their least common multiple

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, number-theory

Given two positive integers `a` and `b`, output two positive integers `c` and `d` such that:

- `c` divides `a`
- `d` divides `b`
- `c` and `d` are co-prime
- the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of `c` and `d` equals the least common multiple of `a` and `b`.

If there are more than one possible answers, you can output only one or all of them.

Test cases:

```
 a  b  c  d
12 18  4  9
18 12  9  4
 5  7  5  7
 3  6  1  6 or 3 2
 9  9  9  1 or 1 9
 6 15  2 15 or 6 5
 1  1  1  1
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: What's to stop me returning (1, LCM)?

Comment: @Neil The requirement that `d` divides `b`

Comment: Maybe you should define LCM or at least not use the acronym.  I didn't know what was being asked for a bit.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> 13 bytes

```
ÆEz®0iṂ$¦€ZÆẸ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//w4ZFesKuMGnhuYIkwqbigqxaw4bhurj///8yMjUwLDM2MA)

> If **a = 2<sup>A</sup> · 3<sup>B</sup> · 5<sup>C</sup> · …** and **b = 2<sup>α</sup> · 3<sup>β</sup> · 5<sup>γ</sup> · …**, then we compute
>
> - **c = 2<sup>A>α?A:0</sup> · 3<sup>B>β?B:0</sup> · 5<sup>C>γ?C:0</sup> · …**
> - **d = 2<sup>A>α?0:α</sup> · 3<sup>B>β?0:β</sup> · 5<sup>C>γ?0:γ</sup> · …**
>
> Now **lcm(c, d) = 2<sup>max(A>α?A:0, A>α?0:α)</sup> · … = 2<sup>max(A, α)</sup> · 3<sup>max(B, β)</sup> · … = lcm(a, b)**
>
> and **gcd(c, d) = 2<sup>min(A>α?A:0, A>α?0:α)</sup> · … = 2<sup>0</sup> · 3<sup>0</sup> · 5<sup>0</sup> · … = 1**.

In other words: start from **(c, d) = (a, b)**. Then, for each prime, divide that prime *all the way out* of the factorization of either **c** or **d**: whichever has the smallest exponent for that prime. (In this implementation, in case of a tie, **c** loses its exponent.)

So if **a = 2250 = 2<sup>1</sup> · 3<sup>2</sup> · 5<sup>3</sup>** and **b = 360 = 2<sup>3</sup> · 3<sup>2</sup> · 5<sup>1</sup>**,

then **c = 2<sup>0</sup> · 3<sup>0</sup> · 5<sup>3</sup> = 125** and **d = 2<sup>3</sup> · 3<sup>2</sup> · 5<sup>0</sup> = 72**.

Jonathan Allan golfed down a whopping 8 bytes! Thank you~

Comment: This is my original algorithm... The Perl algorithm is better.

Comment: Very nice. Here it is in [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//w4ZFWjBp4bmCJMKm4oKsWsOG4bq4////MTYwLDkw)

Comment: Here's another 12 byter `ÆEZ×Ụ’$€$ZÆẸ`

Comment: This now gives `[1,18]` for `[15,18]`. The initial version was returning the correct answer (`[5,18]`).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Any idea why? (I’ll revert to 21B for now.)

Comment: Ah - yes we'd need a filler of zero on the transpose. [`ÆEz®0iṂ$¦€ZÆẸ`](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//w4ZFesKuMGnhuYIkwqbigqxaw4bhurj///8xNSwxOA) should do the trick for 13.

Comment: No need for `®` btw. `ÆEz00iṂ$¦€ZÆẸ` works just as well.

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>143</s> <s>139</s> 123 bytes

```
f=function(a,b,q=1:(a*b))for(i in 1:a)for(j in 1:b)if(!a%%i+b%%j&max(q[!i%%q+j%%q])<2&i*j==min(q[!q%%a+q%%b]))cat(i,j,"\n")
```

(Thanks to @Giuseppe for those 19 bytes off!)

With indentations, newlines and some explanations:

```r
f=function(a,b,
           q=1:(a*b)) #Defined as function arguments defaults to avoid having to use curly brackets
    for(i in 1:a)
        for(j in 1:b)
            if(!a%%i + b%%j & #Is a divided by c and b divided by d
               max(q[!i%%q+j%%q])<2 & #Are c and d coprimes
               i*j==min(q[!q%%a+q%%b])) #Is this the same lcm
                   cat(i,j,"\n") #Then print
```

Test cases:

```
> f=function(a,b,q=1:(a*b))for(i in 1:a)for(j in 1:b)if(!a%%i+b%%j&max(q[!i%%q+j%%q])<2&i*j==min(q[!q%%a+q%%b]))cat(i,j,"\n")
> f(5,7)
5 7 
> f(12,18)
4 9 
> f(6,15)
2 15 
6 5 
> f(1,1)
1 1
```

Comment: `!` has higher precedence than `&` and `|` but lower than `+` and `*`; you should be able to golf down a few bytes that way; i.e., `!i%%q&j%%q` should be equivalent to `!i%%q+j%%q`

Comment: Okay well observation: if `GCD(c,d)==1`, then `LCM(c,d)==c*d`. So we can test `GCD(c,d)==1` and then check if `c*d==a*b/GCD(a,b)` since the latter is `LCM(a,b)`...

Comment: Indeed! (though calculating `a*b/GCD(a,b)` is not shorter than `LCM(a,b)`).

Comment: [120 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcnBCoMwDIDh@56iCpHEdgd3FPskw0MiFBKwUnGwt6@6XX74@Pea3PSs6ZOXQ7eMHCSUOIzIvRClbUd1mt0w8g/2h5AmbBhAvQBYt/IXy7tRgOLtykzTq9PeYlw136cAsL8iM9HCB2qw0D5aqvUE "R – Try It Online") -- anonymous function + literal newline for -3 bytes

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
→ÖF§-⌋⌉ΠmḊ
```

Brute force. Takes and returns lists, and works for more than two numbers too. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkKtR/KipsUjz0Lb/j9omHZ7mdmi57qOe7kc9necW5D7c0fX///9oQyMdQ4tYrmhDCx1DIyBtqmMOJI11zICkpY4lkDTTMTQFKdAxBJJGRqYGOsZmBrEA)

### Explanation

```
→ÖF§-⌋⌉ΠmḊ  Implicit input, say [6,15]
        mḊ  Map divisors: [[1,2,3,6],[1,3,5,15]]
       Π    Cartesian product:[[1,1],[2,1],[1,3],[2,3],[3,1],[1,5],[3,3],[6,1],[1,15],[2,5],[3,5],[6,3],[2,15],[6,5],[3,15],[6,15]]
 Ö          Sort by
  F         reduce by
     ⌉      lcm
   -⌋       minus gcd: [[1,1],[3,3],[2,1],[1,3],[3,1],[6,3],[1,5],[2,3],[6,1],[2,5],[3,15],[1,15],[3,5],[6,15],[2,15],[6,5]]
→           Get last element: [6,5]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 82 bytes

```
#&@@Select[Subsets[Flatten@Divisors[{t=#,r=#2}],{2}],GCD@@#==1&&LCM@@#==t~LCM~r&]&
```

Comment: I am not sure, but could you not use list indexing `Select[...][[1]]` instead of `First@Select[...]` to save a byte?

Comment: yes, but then I could use `#&@@` instead of `[[1]]` to save one more ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
&YFt&X>2:!=*^!Xp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xy3SrUQtws7IStFWK04xouD//2hDMx0FQ7PY/wA)

Same method as Lynn's Jelly solution

It's been a while since I've used any MATL (or matlab for that matter) so many improvements are likely possible.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>90</s> <s>84</s> 80 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(a)(b)` and returns an array of 2 integers.

```js
a=>g=(b,c=1)=>(G=(a,b)=>b?G(b,a%b):a)(c,d=a*b/G(a,b)/c)-1|a%c|b%d?g(b,c+1):[c,d]
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>g=(b,c=1)=>(G=(a,b)=>b?G(b,a%b):a)(c,d=a*b/G(a,b)/c)-1|a%c|b%d?g(b,c+1):[c,d]

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(12)(18))) // [ 4,  9 ]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(18)(12))) // [ 9,  4 ]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f( 5)( 7))) // [ 5,  7 ]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f( 3)( 6))) // [ 1,  6 ] or [ 3, 2 ]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f( 9)( 9))) // [ 9,  1 ] or [ 1, 9 ]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f( 6)(15))) // [ 2, 15 ] or [ 6, 5 ]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f( 1)( 1))) // [ 1,  1 ]
```

#### How?

```js
a =>                            // a = first input
  g = (                         // g = recursive function that takes:
    b,                          //   b = second input
    c = 1                       //   c = first output divisor, initially set to 1
  ) =>                          //
    (G = (a, b) =>              // G = function that takes a and b
      b ? G(b, a % b) : a       //     and returns the greatest common divisor
    )(                          // we call it with:
      c,                        //   - c
      d = a * b / G(a, b) / c   //   - d = LCM(a, b) / c = a * b / GCD(a, b) / c
    ) - 1 |                     // if the result is not 1 (i.e. c and d are not coprime)
    a % c |                     // or c does not divide a
    b % d ?                     // or d does not divide b:
      g(b, c + 1)               //   do a recursive call with c + 1
    :                           // else:
      [c, d]                    //   return [c, d], a valid factorization of the LCM
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <del>50</del> <del>48</del> <del>47</del> <del>45</del> 42 bytes

```hs
(?)=gcd;a!b|c<-div a$a?b=(c*c?b,div b$c?b)
```

Idea: I noticed that `c*d = a*b/gcd(a,b)`. So the algorithm performs two steps:

1. Begin with `c' = a/gcd(a,b)` and `d' = b`. This fulfils all requirements except that `c'` and `d'` have to be co-prime.
2. To make them co-prime, I calculate `e = gcd(c',d')` and then set `c = c'*e` and `d = d'/e`. This keeps all properties (since the combined factors stay the same), but since I remove all shared factors from `d`, I make `c`and `d` coprime.

In my implementation, `c'` is just called `c`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X8Ne0zY9OcU6UTGpJtlGNyWzTCFRJdE@yVYjWSvZPkkHJJCkAmRp/s9NzMyzzU0s8I3XKCjKzCvRK81LLi0qqtRQ1NSM1jA00jG00NTRMLTQMTQC0qY65kDSWMcMSFrqWAJJMx1DU5ACHUPN2P8A)

-3 bytes thanks to Laikoni

Comment: Using a pattern guard to bind `c` saves 3 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X8Ne0zY9OYUrUTGpJtlGNyWzTCFRJdE@yVYjWSvZPkkHJJCkAmRp/s9NzMyzzU0s8I3XKCjKzCvRK81LLi0qqtRQ1NSM1jA00jG00NTRMLTQMTQC0qY65kDSWMcMSFrqWAJJMx1DU5ACHUPN2P8A "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Laikoni Ooh, I didn't even know that trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
Ñ`âʒ.¿I.¿Q}н
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8MSEw4tOTdI7tN8TiANrL@z9/z/a0EjH0CIWAA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9W@f/wxITDi05N0ju0vxKIA2sv7P1fqXR4v5XC4f1KOv@jow2NdAwtYnWiDS10DI2AtKmOOZA01jEDkpY6lkDSTMfQFKRAxzA2FgA)

Comment: Still a brute-force :c

Comment: @LeakyNun: Yeah, there's probably a mathier way to do this :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>91</s> 74 bytes

```hs
a!b=[(x,y)|x<-[1..a],y<-[1..b],rem a x+rem b y+gcd x y<2,lcm a b==lcm x y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoMwFESv8t0l@BV@ilbB9AY9QZpFYqUVo4jtIoHePU3azZthZpineS2TczGawkrFPAb@8UOlqK6NxvB3VuMxrWDAl1kthPIx3sFDGAS6MTdWymxSpONq5g0krGa/AtuPeXvX7Pa7ri6@CJyDYiSQOo6MOiSRtMFz4gnbxB77xBapyQMkruMX)

*Saved **17** bytes thanks to Laikoni*

Comment: ``u*v`div`gcd u v`` saves a byte.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the built-in `lcm` function?

Comment: Also `rem a x+rem b y+gcd x y<2` should work.

Comment: @Laikoni a very good reason:  I didn't even know the builtin `lcm` existed. `rem a x+rem b y+gcd x y<2` works, and I wonder if `rem a x+rem b y+gcd x y+lcm a b-lcm x y<2 `works. There is *maybe* a (mathematical) guarantee that `lcm a b>=lcm x y`.

Comment: Indeed, `lcm a b>=lcm x y` because 1. `x=x1*...*xi` (prime decomposition), `y=y1*...yj`, `lcm x y=z1*...*zk` where `z1,...,zk` are common to `x1,...,xi` and `y1,...,yj`. 2. `a=u1*...*um*x1*...*xi` (prime decomposition), `b=v1*...vn*y1*...yj`, `lcm a b=t1*...*tl` where `t1,...,tl` are common to `u1*...*um*x1*...*xi` and `v1*...vn*y1*...yj`. It's  obvious that `t1,...,tl` contains `z1,...,zk`, thus `lcm a b>=lcm x y`. But that's not useful for writing the condition as a sum.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 126 bytes

```r
function(a,b,g=function(x,y)ifelse(o<-x%%y,g(y,o),y),l=a*b/g(a,b))matrix(c(C<-(1:l)[!l%%1:l],D<-l/C),,2)[g(C,D)<2&!a%%C+b%%D,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtBCoMwFAX3PUVd/PJ/@4LookiJq@QW4iKKCUJUsBb09KnddDczMGvyV62S/8z9Ni4zO3QI9V93HDL6Ib4HXrTaiQ4EPrDI2RFrd@/y8HtEJret4849G624eEVpskh0QgurVcyNAKU0gQ2s6PKWOSLz6Igs2uS5KFFUcjnhiUrSFw)

This takes a different (and apparently less golfy) approach to finding the values than [the other R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142881/67312).

Explanation:

```r
function(a,b){
 G <- function(x,y)ifelse(o<-x%%y,G(y,o),y) #gcd function, vectorized for x,y
 l <- a*b/g(a,b)                            #lcm of a,b
 C <- (1:l)[!l%%1:l]                        #divisors of l
 D <- l/C                                   #l/C is the other half of the pair
 rel_prime <- G(C, D) < 2                   #pairs where C,D are relatively prime, lol, GCD
 a_div <- !a%%C                             #divisors of a
 b_div <- !b%%D                             #divisors of b
 C <- C[rel_prime & a_div & b_div]
 D <- D[rel_prime & a_div & b_div]          #filter out the bad pairs
 matrix(c(C,D),,ncol = 2)                   #matrix of pairs, returned
}
```

except I shoehorn all the definitions as default arguments and do all the calculations on one line for the golfiness.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
(*/:"1)&.|:&.(_&q:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcNNCoMwFADhfU4xuIiJSOxL8e@JNxFclAZxU4pbe/ZUZL7ZczqYlQfX2VWNFuJtONUGt9qv@uxNESjTrCU1PyUdxrxf24c14qbkFyQiwy3S0vOkY7zqkBZB8h8)

Based on @Lynn's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142892/6710).

### Explanation

```
(*/:"1)&.|:&.(_&q:)  Input: [a, b]
              _&q:   Get exponenets of each prime
         |:&         Transpose
  /:"1 &             Grade each row
 *                   Multiply elementwise
       &.|:          Transpose
           &. _&q:   Convert exponents back to numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 75 bytes

```python
def f(x):n=1;exec'n+=1;j=k=1\nwhile x[j]%k<1:k*=n**j;j^=1\nx[j]/=k/n;'*x[0]
```

Input is taken as a list, which the function modifies in place.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5NDoIwEIXXcIrZkGptgq0B@bEnwbrREmjJQAjEevraegAXk@/Lm7d4y2cbZhTev3QP/cEdG5S81U4/CZ6CGWklv@N7GCcNrjMqszfeWCqRUtOaR3zGOJc2x5ZQ152V7@cVHIwIHRcMeKVYsCqYiFYwuEZeGJSRNYM6sgyF4lcNopo0WdYRNyCZ2CEcgQy2fZl0GMnSJG79V/Ff)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 129 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[[c,d]for c in range(1,-~a)for d in range(1,-~b)if((gcd(c,d)<2)*a*b/gcd(a,b)==c*d/gcd(c,d))>a%c+b%d]
from math import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYw7DsIwEAV7TrFNJK8xihIahDAXCSnWXpxYwh9Zbmi4ukkKCsqZ0Xv5XdcUz83pR3tRMExAylynySqeXSpgwUcoFJenGNTpQ7hL/pcGvRNisSy2Fd5GlCRNv/P2hVpbyf2v4p06ezQdzwdXUoBAdQUfcipVtlx8rMKJYVQwXBDbFw) or [Try the test suite.](https://tio.run/##VYzLDoIwFAX3fMXdkPTWGlKID4z4I8iiDwtNbEuabtz46xUWJLicOZkzf9IUfJNN98xv4aQWIJi89b1iejAhggLrIQo/vghnx6/AVep/KdEaQkalyVLhvUYqqKxWXr6w6xTV1bbiQ5TqIEs9FCYGB06kCaybQ0w0z9H6RAzhNQN@RSw2cWJw2WHD4LzDlkG7Q77EiPkH)

Outputs all possible combinations in  the form of a nested list.

Comment: You and your bitwise stuff... `-~a` and `-~b` can just be rewritten as `a+1` and `b+1` for readability :P

Comment: @Stephen As you can see, I specialize in [tag:obfuscation]

Comment: Doesn't work for my newly added second testcase.

Comment: @LeakyNun Rolled back. Didn't have time to check the validity of the golf.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>19 15</s>  14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-4 with pointer from [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun) (use divisor built-in)

<sup>I am almost 100% certain this is not the way to actually do this one, but here is a first attempt.

Let's see who outgolfs it with a seven or eight byter!

Yep... see [Lynn's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142892/53748) with explanation!</sup>

```
g/÷æl/
ÆDp/ÇÐṂ
```

A monadic link taking a list of the two numbers and returning a list of lists of the possibilities.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//Zy/Dt8OmbC8Kw4ZEcC/Dh8OQ4bmC////MTIsMTg)**

#### How?

```
g/÷æl/  - Link: gcd divided by lcm: list [x, y]
g/      - reduce by gcd = gcd(x, y)
   æl/  - reduce by lcm = lcm(x,y)
  ÷     - divide

ÆDp/ÇÐṂ - Main link: list [a, b]    e.g. [160, 90]
ÆD      - divisors (vectorises)          [[1,2,4,5,8,10,16,20,32,40,80,160],[1,2,3,5,6,9,10,15,18,30,45,90]]
  p/    - reduce by Cartesian product    [[1,1],[1,2],...,[1,90],[2,1],[2,2],...,[2,90],....,[160,90]]
     ÐṂ - entries for which this is minimal:
    Ç   -   call the last link (1) as a monad
```

Comment: *Let's see who outgolfs it with a seven or eight byter!* - Don't think so...

Comment: You think six? ...FIVE?!

Comment: :P No... I don't think less than ~13-15 is possible (Dennis would disagree, of course!)

Comment: Divisor built-in?

Comment: Yeah `ÆD` but (shrug) brain obviously not in gear...

Comment: @LeakyNun - thanks, I'm still of the mind there will be a clever trick :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan of course there is, but up till now everybody has been using brute force

Comment: @LeakyNun That's probably not what Jonathan meant...

Comment: *Let's see who outgolfs it with a seven or eight byter!* with two numbers both extending to infinity? don't think so

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), 148 bytes

```python
from sympy import*
a,b=input()
c=d=z=1
while(a/c*c+b/d*d<a+b)+gcd(c,d)-1+(lcm(c,d)!=lcm(a,b)):E=c==d==z;Q=c==z;d=+E or Q+d;c=+Q or-~c;z+=E
print c,d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcwxDoMgFADQnVPQDfwaY5OmSfGPHsAj6KetJCKE0jQy9OoUu73p@T0ubjvn/AjO8tdu/c6N9S7Eik31jGbz7ygkI9SYsGOfxax3MbVUEcytrnQ/wSzhSVpQrWXTgVjJ/n3CQyWR8jYgYRkwqfFQUhph4C7wEbQihLG4@ZJKgAPzwWyRlyJncan5Vf4A)

-1 thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech).

This answer works in Python 2 (not Python 3), using `sympy.gcd` and `sympy.lcm` instead of `math.gcd` and `math.lcm` which are only available in Python 3. And yes, this is brute force :)

Comment: Golfing in progress...

Comment: You may be able to save a byte by defining `Q=c==z;` (+7 bytes) at the start of the while loop and replacing `or(c==z)+d` with `or Q+d` (-4 bytes) and `c=+(c==z)or` with `c=+Q or` (-4 bytes). ([TIO](https://tio.run/##HcxBDoIwEEDRPaeou5aBEEyMiWWWHIAjwIxKE0qbWmNg4dVrcfXf6vstzm49p/QIzorXZv0mjPUuxFKP1YRm9e8olSZk3LEtPrNZ7nJsqCSYGi65G2FS8CSWVLGqW5AL2b9PeChPlLoNSIi77o/wIUbohQtiAM5vGLLrL@kdsC98MGsUeZGSvFTiqn4))

Comment: Just as a question, are you using the `+` operator in `d=+E` or `c=+(c==z)` to convert a boolean into an integer?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Yes I am, since you can't use `True` and `False` instead of `1` and `0` in sympy.

Comment: That is the first instance I ever saw where the vanilla `+...` has any use.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Probably has no use in real life though...real life code should be clear, e.g. `1 if condition else 0`...however some things may be to be thought of as `-x`, `0`, `+x` instead of `-x`, `0`, `x`, and that's where `+` strikes in for clarity

Comment: You can probably also operator overload it on your own classes; though I have not yet found any real use for it there either.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>32</s> <s>26</s> <s>24</s> <s>22</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
Ó0ζεD`›0sǝ}øεā<ØsmP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf8wNWFiMWX//8OTMM62zrVEYOKAujBzx519w7jOtcSBPMOYc21Q//9bNjAsIDkwXf8tZA) I still have no idea how to write in this language, but at least it's not a brute-force algorithm. Explanation:

```
Ó                       Get exponents of prime factors (vectorised)
 0ζ                     Zip, filling with 0
   ε      }             For each prime
    D`                  Extract the pair of exponents
      ›0sǝ              Overwrite the smaller with 0
           ø            Zip back into two lists of prime exponents
            ε           For each list (} implied)
             ā<Ø        Get a list of primes
                sm      Raise each prime to the exponent
                  P     Take the product
```

Comment: What’s it doing?

Comment: Same as yours, but by actually factorising and comparing the exponents and recombining the factors.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 72 bytes

```perl6
{([X] map {grep $_%%*,1..$_},@^a).grep:{([lcm] @a)==([lcm] $_)==[*] $_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/WiM6IlYhN7FAoTq9KLVAQSVeVVVLx1BPTyW@VschLlFTDyRsBVSWk5wbq@CQqGlrC2WrxAPZ0VogRm3t/@JEkIkaGoZGOgqGFpqa1lxwEQugiBGyiKmOgjky31hHwQyZb6mjYInMNwMaYIpiJFAEZMd/AA)

Takes a list (a, b). Returns a list of all possible lists (c, d).

Explanation:

```perl6
-> @ab {
    # Generate all pairs (c, d)
    ([X]
         # where c divides a and d divides b.
         map { grep $_%%*, 1..$_ }, @ab)
    # Only keep pairs with lcm(a, b) = lcm(c, d) and lcm(c, d) = c * d.
    # The latter implies gcd(c, d) = 1.
    .grep: { ([lcm] @ab) == ([lcm] $_) == [*] $_ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>126</s> 121 bytes

```python
def f(a,b):
 c=[1,1];p=2
 while p<=a*b:
	t=m=1
	while(a*b)%p<1:m*=p;t=b%p<1;a/=p**(a%p<1);b/=p**t
	p+=1;c[t]*=m
 return c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY9BDoMgEEXXzCnYNAFK0kBjq@JsvYRxAVajSbXE0DQ9vRXq6r/3N3/Gf8P4WvS2PfqBDsxKx0ugHTZKqtZ41EA/4/Tsqa/QClcCCTijApJatlf85CtVzgK9CeiiGHtBLwSzUbhxyQIQf0Zluia0Amegax/e60K7tFwfy8Sv0xJos1srj3sAaqa0VBk/IE@QS6UjZPIe4ypvMQpZxLj9bX@Cw/YD)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
Ụ€’×
ÆEz0ÇZÆẸ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//4buk4oKs4oCZw5cKw4ZFejDDh1rDhuG6uP///1sxMiwgMThd) My first Jelly answer! Edit: `ÆEz0µỤ€’×µZÆẸ` also works for 13 bytes. Explanation:

```
ÆE              Get prime factor exponents of both values (vectorises)
  z0            Zip but fill the shorter array with 0
    µ           New monadic link
     Ụ€         Grade up each pair (1-indexed)
       ’        Convert to 0-indexing (vectorises)
        ×       Multiply each pair by its grade (vectorises)
         µ      New monadic link
          Z     Zip back into separate lists of prime factor exponents
           ÆẸ   Turn prime exponent lists back into values (vectorises)
```

Answer (score 1):

## PARI/GP, 86 bytes

This just does what Lynn says in her answer:

```
f(a,b)=forprime(p=2,a*b,v=valuation(a,p);w=valuation(b,p);if(w<v,b/=p^w,a/=p^v));[a,b]
```

If I do not count the `f(a,b)=` part, it is 79 bytes.